# Why do I get an undefined errors for referencing "built-in" functions in Dr. Racket?

Tags: function, package, undefined, racket

I'm going through the online CS 61AS textbook and trying to complete the exercises in Dr. Racket.

However, when I attempt to call several built-in functions mentioned in the CS 61AS textbook, Dr. Racket claims those procedures are undefined.

I get errors when calling the following functions:

```
word
sentence
butfirst
butlast
trace
...and more!
```

But other built-in functions seem to work for me, like `quote` and `equal?`.

Are these functions really built into Racket or do I need to install some sort of package or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not built into Racket. But Racket treats languages as libraries:

You can go into "Install Package" and install the `simply-scheme` package.

Then, replace `#lang racket` with `#lang simply-scheme`

```
> bf
#<procedure:bf>
```